# Axios retry file upload (PUT method) with interceptor

Tags: javascript, axios, jwt, axios-retry

**The issue I face is that my axios interceptor is not retrying file upload requests using PUT method.**

If my JWT tokens expire in the process of trying to upload the file my interceptor refreshes them but doesn't retry the file request upload, all other requests work and get retried once the tokens are refreshed. Wasn't able to find a solid answer to this problem so before sharing a ton of code just wanted to check if this is common.

So my question is this the desired behavior? What would be the workaround? Do a token refresh each time before calling upload request?

My current interceptor looks something as follows:

[image]

Thank you for any pointers/help!

Comment: Could you paste some code for context

Comment: Included the main parts of my current interceptor.

Comment: One thing you should know about axios is that this configuration you have used will be the general configuration for all requests that are made with axios throughout your app. Adding interceptors to the `axios` importation directly makes it the default interceptor setting throughout your app.

So basically, let's assume that you wanted to upload 1 file and then some seconds later you wanted to upload another file. Assuming in both uploads, the `setup` function is called, the last configuration created by the last upload is what is going to exist on axios throughout your app.

Comment: So, don't add interceptors to your axios importation directly. You should create an instance and then add the interceptors to that instance. 
You do that with the `axios.create` function as it says [here](https://axios-http.com/docs/instance) in the documentation.
It is possible that subsequest requests are overriding the configurations of previous requests and so you're not getting an appropriate response.